# WCF Service cant seem to return Object to Form Application

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, wcf, object

I am trying to make a WCF-service in Visual Studio with a windows form application as a client.

The problem is that I can't seem to receive the data from  my service when calling the method (I would like to get an object of Customer returned) -
the data has to be stored within the service, no database. (Is this possible? no database?)

Here is MyService.cs:

```
 public class MyService : IMyService
{
    Store store = new Store();

public void RegisterCustomer(string name, string pass)
    {
        Customer c = new Customer(name, pass);
        store.Customers.Add(c);
    }

  public Customer GetCustomer(string name)
    {
        Customer c = new Customer();
        foreach(Customer i in store.Customers)
        {
            if (i.UserName.Equals(name))
            {
                c = i;
            }                    
        }
        return c;           
    }
```

The operations and datamembers are declared in the IMyService Interface

```
namespace WcfService
{
[ServiceContract]
public interface IMyService
{
 [OperationContract]
    // register - klant bestaat niet --> voeg toe aan klantenlijst -1.1-
    void RegisterCustomer(string name, string pass);

 [OperationContract]
    // login - klant bestaat niet --> voeg toe aan klantenlijst
    Customer GetCustomer(string name);

 [DataContract]
public class Customer
{
    string username;
    string password;
    int saldo;

    [DataMember]
    public string UserName { get{ return username; }set{ username = value; }
    }

    [DataMember]
    public string Password{get { return password; }set { password = value; }
    }

    [DataMember]
    public int Saldo{get { return saldo; }set { saldo = value; }
    }
    public Customer() { }

    public Customer(string name, string pass)
    {
        this.username = name;
        this.password = pass;
        this.saldo = 100;
    }
}
```

our reference inside the form1: form

```
//reference
    ServiceReference1.MyServiceClient client = new ServiceReference1.MyServiceClient();
```

The form app that makes the call to the service

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string name = textBox4.Text;
        string pass;

        if (client.CustomerExists(name))
        {
            label9.Text = "De opgegeven naam bestaat al";
        }
        else {
            pass = client.CreatePass(name); // does work
            client.RegisterCustomer(name,pass);    // does not work           

            Customer c = client.GetCustomer(name); // does not work
            label9.Text = "welkom: " + c.UserName + "\njouw pass: " +c.Password;
        } }
```

This line of code should return me the object of Customer... but it does not.

```
Customer c = client.GetCustomer(name); // does not work
```

Comment: Using a variable for storing data on the service should be used with session and I do not recommend that for long life data because session/service reference aren't designed to be keep alive a long time. Have you tried to modify your GetCustomer to return a "fake sample Customer" ? What is the error (exception, return nothing instead of expected) ? Have you tried to debug your service to watch the content of your store collection ? WCF isn't a piece of cake and could have a lot of different behavior depending the configuration !

Comment: hi, thanks for the comment.  I've tried the idea of creating a Customer in the method "client.GetCustomer(name)" this all works and indeed returns me the Customer Object and can be set as text on the label9 when using the c.UserName and c.Password.  the only problem is that I would like to hold a list of Customers in the "store-variable" that will be accessible every time i use one of my methods. but right now, calling one method after the other, calling the "store-variable" will leave me with an "empty" store-Object

Comment: Check that the InstanceContextMode ServiceBehaviorattribute of your service is set to PerSession. Remark : Your store will be reseted when the client close the connection !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Solution:*

The InstanceContextMode was indeed the problem:

```
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode= InstanceContextMode.Single)]
```

**This is wrong:**

```
 public class MyService : IMyService{
    Store store = new Store();

    //your methods here

}
```

**This is right:**

```
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode= InstanceContextMode.Single)]
    Store store = new Store();

    //your methods here

}
```

+1 to Marco